# What if administrator changes price of a product while someone is about to buy the product

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I am using drupal commerce. I am facing a problem of price shown to buyer is different than the price what he finally pays.

Suppose we have a product p1 with price x.

If a buyer add p1 to his shopping cart and checkout. On review page just before make payment, price shown to him is x, if at the same time administrator changes price of p1 to y. Then user will pay y finally while he was expecting to pay x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typically not a problem unless a) you have a lot of customers frequently making purchases (good for you! :)), and b) you change your prices very frequently

The solution is:

a) change prices (or, more generally, change ANYTHING) off-hours, when customers aren't likely to be using the system

... and/or ...

b) schedule a "maintenance window",  during which you lock out user sessions in order to change prices, items and/or schema (the customary approach).

Answer (score 0):

This is what durpal build as.
I think other store also build in this way.